# CXF Conflicts xmlschema and xmlschema-core Dependency

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jakarta-ee, cxf

I have a problem with my cxf dependencies. There is a really huge project that ı working and there are lots of dependencies.

My problem is with xmlschema and xmlschema-core dependencies. There is no older versions of dependencies in my pom files, but i am getting the following exception. Do you have any idea about the problem ?

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: QUALIFIED
 at org.apache.cxf.service.model.SchemaInfo.setSchema(SchemaInfo.java:146)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.extractSchema(SchemaUtil.java:136)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.getSchemas(SchemaUtil.java:73)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.getSchemas(SchemaUtil.java:65)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.SchemaUtil.getSchemas(SchemaUtil.java:60)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.getSchemas(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:372)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:339)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceBuilder.buildServices(WSDLServiceBuilder.java:203)
 at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLServiceFactory.create(WSDLServiceFactory.java:142)
 at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromWSDL(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:383)
 at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:506)
 at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:242)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:205)
 at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:101)
 at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:90)
 at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:155)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:155)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.createPort(ServiceImpl.java:465)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:332)
 at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.ServiceImpl.getPort(ServiceImpl.java:319)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: QUALIFIED error. It is also comes from dependency confilict, but the weirdest thing is there is no dependency in the dependency hierarchy. The root cause of above exception is missing versions in some dependencies. I need cxf-rt-core 2.5.2 which has internal dependecy of xmlschema-core. Following code block is taken from cxf-rt-core 2.5.2 pom.

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.ws.xmlschema</groupId>
       <artifactId>xmlschema-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

There is no version information as seen above. This causes the error. If there is no version provided in the pom file, it matches the first dependency in the repository, it is generally older versions. There should be carefully investigated the dependencies and its version. If there is a dependency which has not version, it may cause similar error. All dependency conflicts should be excluded as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28463377/892994), then updating all the dependencies will solve the issue. There should be given special attention to local repository, and make sure that there is no older versions of dependencies.